# Passar o html da página via GET Ajax

Tags: c#, html, jquery, ajax

Olá,

estou tentando baixar um arquivo excel passando o html da página, porém ao tentar enviar o html, ele está passando como null.

**Ajax**

```
function exportarExcel() {
    var html = $("body").html();
    $.ajax({
        url: location.href = '@Url.Action("ExportExcel")',
        type: 'get',
        data: {
            Html: html,
        },
    });
}
```

**Controller**

```
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    [HttpGet()]
    public void ExportExcel(string Html)
    {
        Classes.Export.ToExcelHtml(Response, Html);
    }
```

**Export**

```
        public static void ToExcelHtml(HttpResponseBase Response, string html)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/x-msexcel";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename = Faturamento.xls");
        Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        StringWriter tw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);
        Response.Write(html);
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: mostre o seu `Classes.Export.ToExcelHtml()`

Comment: E via GET vai ser complicado...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via GET não vai ser possível, mude seu javascript e a controller para trabalhar com post e utilize um FileResult para fazer o download do arquivo.

```
function exportarExcel()
{
var html = $("body").html();
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("ExportExcel")',
        type: 'post',
        data: { Html: html },
        success: () => { window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Download")' }
    });
}
```

**Controller**

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
[HttpPost]
public void ExportExcel(string html)
{
    //Classes.Export.ToExcelHtml(Response, Html);

    byte[] fileBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html);
    string fileName = "Faturamento.xls";
    TempData["Download"] = File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
}

[HttpGet]
public FileResult Download()
{
    return TempData["Download"] as FileResult;
}
```

Comment: Mas é possível realizar o download do arquivo utilizando o [HttpPost]?

Comment: sim, vou editar a resposta, com a informação da sua classe que só está fazendo um response

Comment: também tentei algo semelhante a este caso: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916340/complex-type-is-getting-null-in-a-apicontroller-parameter , mas não rolou

Comment: @Flavio veja minha edição